# What 90's movie had one surviving alien on a ship controlled by its brain?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship, horror, mind-control

I have been racking my brain for years on which apparently is a very forgotten alien movie that I have googled, and googled...So apparently it must be a rarity. It had to have come out between 1995 and 2000, but I believe it was more so 1998 - 2000 to narrow it down more. I remember a small crew investigating a strange alien spaceship, and all of the aliens being dead except the one in the control center of the ship where it  appeared dead, but wasn't. Its brain was still somehow alive and controlling the spaceship through the equipment it had on its head. The two remaining crew survivors try to take the control equipment over from the alien. The aliens looked a bit like the bad gremlins do after they mutate into their worst state. I can't find it anywhere! Does it jog anyone else's memory? It is older. Back in 1999 or 2000, I was at a sleepover and the adults had it on. It was so long ago that I can't remember it clearly enough to find it easily. I believe it is one of those lost films that didn't get enough attention.

Comment: Have you asked any of the adults who were at the sleepover?

Comment: They are as lost as that movie is. I have no contact with them, and no clue where they are today.

Comment: Gremlins in space? Sounds like Critters 4; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hb4qBrI3nP8

Comment: It's not Critters. I think it is so rare not many have heard of it.

Comment: @Oddity100 Was it a ship or a SPACE ship?

Comment: Spaceship! It was a really weird movie, but it was a good one.

Comment: For those who keep editing my question, I don't like that feature. People tend to go overboard with it, and all it is is aggravating to the person who took the time first to write it. Also they only want to edit my question instead of responding. Now I find that to be a bit rude.

Comment: Are you sure it was a standalone movie, and not an episode of a show?

Comment: I am pretty sure. It ran for a really long time. At least 1 and half to 2 hours. I am not completely certain though. Maybe that is why I can't find it.

Comment: People here are not only allowed but *encouraged* to edit questions to improve them. Paragraphs are a *definite* improvement.  Editors are *not* being rude, they're being helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Is it possible that this was the TV version of Steven King's "The Tommyknockers"? The alien spaceship was buried under the earth near a small town. The aliens' technology drained life energy from people and converted it to psionic energy to power the ship and then back to life energy to regenerate the crew. Jimmi Smits sacrificed himself to save the town by donning the control headpiece and launching the ship to it's destruction.

Comment: It is the right one! I appreciate it!